# × TypeError: history.push is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typeerror

```
18 | const {error,loading,userInfo} = userLogin;
  19 | useEffect(() =>{
  20 |   if (userInfo) {
> 21 |     history.push(redirect);
     | ^  22 |   }
  23 | },[userInfo,history,redirect])
  24 |
```

I have these Login.js File I want to login in my app but it is showing the error

Comment: What is `history`? It seems like it's not an array at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to use react-router-dom's useHistory hook, and in that case you'll need to import it first

`import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";`

and then declare it before using it like so

`const history = useHistory();`

For more information on React-router and how to use it, [see the github](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom v6, they changed the way to redirect.

```js
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom' //this is the import in the head of the file

 | const {error,loading,userInfo} = userLogin;
  const navigate = useNavigate()
 
  19 | useEffect(() =>{
  20 |   if (userInfo) {
> 21 |     navigate(redirect);
     | ^  22 |   }
  23 | },[userInfo,history,redirect])
  24 |
```